# Combining . (dot) and & (ampersand) in SASS

Tags: css, sass

### SASS syntax:

```
.rule{
    &-first.&-second{
        /*rules*/
    }
}
```

Generates error "Invalid CSS..."

### Expected output:

```
.rule-first.rule-second{
    /*rules*/
}
```

**Can it be done? How?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with `@at-root` and interpolation. You will need to be using a version of SASS that supports those features.

```
.rule {
    @at-root #{&}-first#{&}-second{
        /*rules*/
    }
}
```

Outputs to:

```
.rule-first.rule-second {
  /*rules*/
}
```

Demo: http://sassmeister.com/gist/f7f9e25a0896e47e0adc

Comment: LibSass 3.2.5 and Ruby Sass 3.4.14 don't need the `@at-root`, it'll work as intended without. I don't know about older versions.